# knockout: How to call the functions of another view model

Tags: knockout.js

I am using the knockout.js with the asp.net web api. I have created the messaging related functionality. i have created two separate view models one for sending the message and other for displaying the message.
I am facing the issue to implement the following functionality.

```
function SendMessagesViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.SendMessage = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: _pageURL + "/api/Communication/SendMessage",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(message),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                    if (response == true) {                       
                    // Call the DisplayMessage function of DisplayMessagesViewModel
                }
                },  
        });
        }
}

function DisplayMessagesViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.DisplayMessage = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: _pageURL + "/api/Communication/DisplayMessage",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(message),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                    if (response == true) {                       
                    //set observable which will be used to bind the html
                }
                },  
        });
        }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what your issue is. What exactly is your problem.

Comment: After sending the message i want to display the recently added message. thats why i am trying to call DisplayMessage of DisplayMessagesViewModel() function form SendMessagesViewModel().

Comment: I would suggest passing an instance of the `DisplayMessagesViewModel` into the `SendMessagesViewModel` as a dependency, either in the constructor or in the function. This will give you access to viewmodel so you can call the functions you want

Comment: i am new with knockout can you elaborate with sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an instance of the `DisplayMessagesViewModel` into the `SendMessagesViewModel` as a dependency, either in the constructor or in the function. This will give you access to the viewmodel so you can call the functions you want

**Option 1.** In constructor:

```
function SendMessagesViewModel(displayMessagesViewModel) {
    var self = this;
    self.SendMessage = function (message) {
        $.ajax({
            url: _pageURL + "/api/Communication/SendMessage",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(message),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                if (response == true) {                       
                    // Call the DisplayMessage function of DisplayMessagesViewModel
                    displayMessagesViewModel.DisplayMessage();
                }
            },  
        });
    }
}
```

and used like this

```
//..other js code
var displayMessagesViewModel = new DisplayMessagesViewModel();
//dependency injected at creation of view model
var sendMessagesViewModel = new SendMessagesViewModel(displayMessagesViewModel);
// when ready to call function:
var message = { message:"Hello world" };
sendMessagesViewModel.SendMessage(message);
//..other js code
```

**Option 2.** In function

```
function SendMessagesViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.SendMessage = function (message, displayMessagesViewModel) {
        $.ajax({
            url: _pageURL + "/api/Communication/SendMessage",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(message),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                if (response == true) {                       
                    // Call the DisplayMessage function of DisplayMessagesViewModel
                    displayMessagesViewModel.DisplayMessage();
                }
            },  
        });
    }
}
```

and used like this

```
//..other js code
var displayMessagesViewModel = new DisplayMessagesViewModel();
var sendMessagesViewModel = new SendMessagesViewModel();
//when ready to call function
var message = { message:"Hello World" };
//dependency injected when calling function
sendMessagesViewModel.SendMessage(message, displayMessagesViewModel);  
//..other js code
```

Comment: If is used on the constructor it will be obligatory pass the parameter in all the instances?

Comment: @rome3ro constructor dependencies are explicit dependencies, so yes, they will be needed for all instances.